# Hibernate objectgeneration tool

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipse-plugin

I have found one eclipse plugin (DB Importer) for Hibernate, which helps to generate annotation based Java Entity classes direct from data base. So that we no need to write any annotation configuration for hibernate Entities.It works very fine.
The tool is available [here](http://objectgeneration.com)

I would like to know

1. Is this tool is really used in industries?
2. Is there any disadvantages by using this tool?

I am asking these questions because, i did not find much information regarding this tool.
Please correct me if i am asking wrong.

Comment: what is the plugin name?  can you post a link to it?  As for the second question, I think the only disadvantage might be that you have to set it up, obviously that plugin won't be included in your jar.  You will be able to modify the source it produces if you don't like it.  Not sure about the first question.

Comment: Sorry i just missed i have edited my post, and added link to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to generate entities from an existing database, I think you are much better off using the [hibernate tools](http://hibernate.org/tools/) which are created and maintained by the Hibernate team (see the reverse engineering tool).

It's been a while since I've used it but from memory you can invoke the reverse engineering from ant/maven/gradle or you can install the [jboss tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/) eclipse plugin and invoke from eclipse. I'm sure you can allso invoke from the command line.